# How can sigaction be both struct and function?

Tags: c, linux, unix, sigaction

I noticed that `sigaction` is defined as both a struct and a function(http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html):

```
    int sigaction(int, const struct sigaction *restrict,
       struct sigaction *restrict);
```

And an example of using it is:

```
    struct sigaction sa;

    /* Set up handler */
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO|SA_RESTART;
    sa.sa_sigaction = timer_expiry;

    /* Setup signal watchdog */
    if (sigaction(SIG_WDOG, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
       printf("ERROR: Failed to set wdog signal with %s",
           strerror(errno));
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C has several name spaces for identifiers; and function identifiers and structure tag identifiers live in different name spaces.

> (C11, 6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers p1) "If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible at any point in a
>   translation unit, the syntactic context disambiguates uses that refer to different entities.
>   Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:
>
> - label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
> - the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any32) of the keywords struct, union, or enum);
> - the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate 
>     name space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the
>     expression used to access the member via the . or -> operator);
> - all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants)

.

Comment: The key point here is this disambiguation by a keyword `struct`. You can't typedef `struct signal` to `signal` - it would make this identifier ambiguous.